# Play say function playback file with G729 Format

Tags: freeswitch

I am using freeswitch and Playing number with *NUMBER PRONOUNCED* and it is play files in .wav format so shall we play with .G729 format ?

FYI : i am using say function playback number

For example : Number 100
Then i can see in freeswitch console :

```
string://digits/1.wav!digits/hundred.wav
```

so is it possible to play file

```
string://digits/1.G729!digits/hundred.G729
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check say_string:

"Using this method you can set the desired file extension as well."

```
<action application="playback" data="${say_string en.wav en current_date_time pronounced ${strepoch()}}" />
```

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+say